# How to use JMS with PHP?

Tags: java, php, jms, openmq

I know JMS and PHP don't get along very easily. I'm in a project where we need to read a jms bus to extract some information using PHP (imagine a java backend application putting messages on the jms buss (using openmq) and a php frontend application that needs to read those messages).

I've tried PHPMQ with no success and I'm wondering if some one else has a suggestion?

Thanks!
Ivan

Comment: Please look at this great answer on this topic (not a JMS topic): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078477/how-to-connect-jms-from-php/4080341#4080341

Comment: actually that answer is great but it basically says "use ActiveMQ" or not use JMS and for some of us that's not an option. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ supports [JMS for PHP](http://activemq.apache.org/php.html) through the Stomp Protocol.

Comment: I looked at ActiveMQ and looks great but I cannot switch to it. The project is stucked with openmq. Will the Stomp protocol and jms for php work the same they do with ActiveMQ ?