# Post JMS message to Weblogic throught PHP

Tags: java, php, weblogic, activemq-classic, stomp

I have a web application that has communicate with other Java web application throught JMS in Weblogic.

I read this answer: 
[How to connect Jms from PHP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078477/how-to-connect-jms-from-php)

I installed ActiveMQ and tried to use it.
But in the Weblogic we need "JMS_FACTORY" and "QUEUE_NAME".
I think it use t3 protocol.

When I want to use is ActiveMQ, it needs tcp protocol.
for example:

> $stomp = new \Stomp('tcp://10.x.x.x:9700');

Is that possible to push messages in the Weblogic queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mix API, wire protocol and client vs server in your question.

WebLogic JMS builds on java constructs all the way from Client to Server. If you really really need queue support I guess you need to create a PHP extension (in C/C++) that uses WebLogic C API (which in turn is a Java bridge). Maybe not smooth or bug free.

The easy way is to write a small WebLogic app that receives messages over HTTP and posts them to a queue. Or, if you can't touch the WebLogic installation, create a Standalone java app that you connect to your PHP in whatever way (HTTP, STOMP, MQTT, memory grid, files, whatever)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestions, If I need to use a interface between PHP and Java and se for example HTTP post request, so what does STOMP library do in PHP? Is that use for implementing JMS queues when both sides are PHP?

Comment: Nah.. STOMP is a wire-protocol for messaging supported by PHP (among other languages). I'm just saying you should pick a transport between Java and PHP that you are familiar with. Maybe you can ask details about that in another question?

Comment: Thanks Petter for your helps